# How to integrate iOS6 app with FaceTime?

Tags: ios6, facetime

How can we integrate our app with FaceTime in iOS 6? Is there an API available? It it possible to integrate FaceTime inside the app, without using a url like `facetime://`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no developer-facing method of utilising FaceTime in the iOS SDK. The best you can do is make a call from your app like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://tel-number"]];
```